# conditional deletion from a list

Tags: php, regex

Imagine if there are two lists and the two lists have some similar items.
i want a third list where any items shared between the first two are removed

so list1.txt:

apple

pear

bus

list2.txt:

apple

pear

output:

bus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
// read both files into an array (each line is an element)
$list1 = file("list1.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$list2 = file("list2.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$merge = array_merge($list1, $list2);
$intersect = array_intersect($list1, $list2);
$not_shared = array_values(array_diff($merge, $intersect));
```

Lets say we have the following files:
**list1.txt**

```
apple
pear
bus
```

**list2.txt**

```
pear
apple
banana
```

Then the output would look like this: (`print_r($not_shared)`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => bus
    [1] => banana
)
```

Comment: i tied this and all it does is output the word 'array'

Comment: @NarisaGlory Sure, because `$not_shared` is an array. To output an array you can use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`. You could also use `implode()` to convert the array back to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$arr_result = array_unique( array_merge($arr_1, $arr_2) );
```

**Or** you can do:

```
$arr_1 = array_diff($arr_1, $arr_2);
$arr_2 = array_diff($arr_2, $arr_1);
```